# VSCode PyLint Not detecting my Python DTO Class Members

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint, python-class

Python Lint does not detect incorrect class members. It continues running my code, I have productName member below,  not productNameTest. It should be sending an error. How can this be resolved ? Currently using VS Code.

**Product Model:**

```
@dataclass(init=False)
class ProductModel:
    
    productId: int
    productName: str
```

**Product Service:**

```
class ProductService:

    def __init__(self, productModel: ProductModel):
        self.productModel= productModel

    def getProductModel(self, curveData):
        self.productModel.productNameTest = "ABCD"  # productNameTest is not a member and should be giving error
```

Comment: "# productNameTest is not a member and should be giving error" Why do you believe that? By default, user-defined Python objects can have arbitrary attributes added to them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there anyway to confine it to a set of defined members?

Comment: You can use `__slots__`

Comment: OK. The code you'e posted makes no sense. Python is **not** Java. Don't assume that the langauges work the same. For example, why do you expect `productModel` to be *defined anywhere?* It isn't. Please read a tutorial on Python class definitions instead of asking random questions: the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)  would be a good place to start.

Comment: I know any attribute is allowed, I guess my pylint is not showing errors, cc @juanpa.arrivillaga maybe, I should rephrase question, thanks

Comment: can someone reopen this, I added update for VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good first question :)

This look like a false negative in pylint (bad understanding of data classes ?), you can open a bug or a pull request to fix the problem in [pylint's github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues).

By the way, contrary to what was said in the comment, your code make sense. The only thing is that you don't have to do explicit getter/setter in python. You can have public attribute:

```
class ProductService:

    def __init__(self, product_model: ProductModel):
        self.product_model= product_model
```

or private attributes...

```
class ProductService:

    def __init__(self, productModel: ProductModel):
        self.__product_model= product_model

    @property
    def product_model(self):
        return self.__product_model


    @product_model.setter
    def product_model(self, value):
        self.__product_model = value
```

And in both case the calling code will be `obj.product_model` or `obj.product_model = new_value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, productModel: ProductModel):
    self.product_model = product_model
```

and not

```
def __init__(self, productModel: ProductModel):
    self.__product_model = product_model
```

product_model is the member property; __product_model is hidden inside

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).